# "Translate" cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm struggling using cURL within PHP. I'm not sure what I need to do to "translate" this:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}:{password}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @profile.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

into PHP to execute it there.

This is all I've got so far, but I'm feeling like I'm not even close:

```
$url2 = 'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?raw_scores=false&csv_headers=false&consumption_preferences=true&version=2017-02-01';
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Language: en';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en';

$ch2 = curl_init( $url2 );
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars2);
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response2 = curl_exec( $ch2 );
var_dump($response2);
```

Comment: Actually you are pretty close. You are just missing the authentication piece from what I see. What output are you getting from the above script?

Comment: That's the piece where I think I'm stuck. I don't know what `-u` is and how to "translate" that to PHP. I figured out the headers, but that's it

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are just missing the authentication piece:

```
curl_setopt( $ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "yourUsername:yourPassword");
```

Check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Also, you can do it this way, which can be a little easier:

```
curl_setopt_array( $ch2, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myvars2,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => $request_headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'yourUsername:yourPassword'
);
```

Comment: Super helpful...thanks. I'm authenticated now, but I must be passing the data incorrectly. This is the first bit of what I need: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Language: en' --header 'Accept-Language: en' -d 'A BUNCH OF PLAIN TEXT HERE'` I've got everything but the `-d` part. What's the "command" for that?

Comment: @jonmrich what do you need to send via that parameter?

Comment: What I'm missing is what I need for for the `CURLOPT_????` part? The data is just complete, plain text.